# enum type in C++

Tags: c++, enums

This works:

```
enum TPriority 
{
    EPriorityIdle = -100,
    EPriorityLow = -20,
    EPriorityStandard = 0,
    EPriorityUserInput = 10,
    EPriorityHigh = 20
};

TPriority priority = EPriorityIdle;
```

But this doesn't work:

```
TPriority priority = -100;
```

Any reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works too, but you need explicit type

```
TPriority priority = (TPriority)-100;
```

Answer (score 4):

shortly put: it defeats the purpose of having an enum

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign an int to an enum, even if the value matches one of the enum's values.

However, casting will work:

```
TPriority priority = static_cast<TPriority>(-100);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no type conversion from the values of an enum type to the enum type itself. Only the other way around.